# Restrict sorting to defined range for Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, worksheet

I need to distribute about 100 spreadsheets to different users, and get their feedback on each row.
I have say 120 columns by 2,000 rows, and that's 240,000 cells.

I want to lock down these 240,000 cells, so any sorting on the sheet does not happen unless the sorting is applied to the full 240,000 cells.... this is to prevent unexperienced users from selecting only a few columns or a few cells and apply the sorting, and corrupt the data.  Anyone with best practice on this?   I am afraid I will get fired if I do not find a solution... thanks to you all, gurus.

Comment: locking sorting does not work; i WANT them to sort; but i only want them to sort a defined range; whenever sorting happens, it must happen to the exact cells in the defined range only.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a pivot table and use some slicers to automate the sorting. Link to the data on another sheet and then hide that sheet so the actual data cannot be directly accessed. If you have SharePoint, publish the workbook and just enable the one sheet with your "UI" on it by way of Browser Options in the backstage.